CDK Codepipeline self mutate: pipeline 'already exists in stack'
I am trying to use codepipeline to build/deploy an ECS/EC2 application and its necessary artifacts -- a docker image.
So far i have a pretty simple setup in cdk which creates 3 stages in the CodePipeline console UI. Source -> Build -> Updatepipeline.
The first step grabs the cdk code, the second step runs synth on it and the last step is supposed to change the pipeline if its CDK code has changed since. This is the code doing that
bin/my-app.ts
...
const app = new cdk.App()
const env = { account: 'number', region: 'region' }
new MyPipeline(app, `pipeline`, { env })

lib/pipeline.ts
...
const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'my-pipeline', {
            pipelineName: 'my-pipeline',
            synth: new ShellStep('Synthesize_CDK_Code', {
            input: CodePipelineSource.gitHub(my-infra-repo, 'my-main-branch', { authentication: my-token}),
            commands: [
                  'npm install -g aws-cdk',
                  'npm install',
                  'npx cdk synth'
            ]
            }),
        })

When i manually deploy this for the first time, the pipeline stack creates successfully and the pipeline is automatically triggered. It gets the infra code correctly, builds it correctly and then the UpdatePipeline step fails.
When I check the step i see it fails to update the pipeline cloudformation stack. If I look at the stack the error is my-pipeline already exists in stack .... Well, yeah it already exists, it was just created, but why is the updatePipeline trying to recreate the stack? Should the first deploy be done in a special way?

Are you using Docker Asset for your CodeBuild stage? Maybe it's this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodePipeline.html#dockerenabledforselfmutation

good thought, but I have not even added that yet. The code you see is all I have. A simple pipeline with a synth step to cdk synth the infrastructure code

Your pipeline does not deploy anything currently, as it has no stages. That might be what's tripping it up - it can't work in this state.

I have tried adding stages to it. I removed everything and left it as simple as possible for debugging purposes.

I'm not sure if it can work properly without deploying anything.

Ah, i found the problem. In my repo I had a different pipeline defined, and I was testing using CodePipeline locally. The problem is that the self mutate step uses the code in the repo to mutate, not the one i just pushed. So it was trying to recreate the old pipeline which had the same logical name.

How does "code in the repo" differ from "code you just pushed"?
You might want to post and accept an answer.

yup, just posted an answer. Hopefully it's clear but i can follow up in comments if not

Got it - you didn't push.

The issue here was that I was deploying the changes manually using the cdk cli, but the self mutate step of the pipeline was making pipeline changes based on the CDK code in my guithub repo.
Since my github repo still had old code that used the Pipeline construct, it was trying to recreate it and failing because both had the same logical id.
